# python: container to memorize a large number of images

Tags: python, database

I have to store/retrieve a large number of images to use in my program.
Each image is small: an icon 50x50, and each one has associated a string which is the path the icon is related to.

Since they are so small I was thinking if there is some library which allows to store all of them in a single file. 
I would need to store both the image and the path string.

I don't know if pickle is a possible choice - I also heard about much more complicated libraries such as HDF5...

thanks for your help!

alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isnt this maybe easier? (stolen here http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/44238-pickle-image)

```
import Image, pickle, cStringIO

i = open('button_home.gif', 'rb')
i.seek(0)
w = i.read()
i.close()
dic = {'1':w,'2':w,'3':w,'4':w}

F=open('allicons.dat','w')
pickle.dump(dic,F)
F.close()

#Ok now you take your pickled string and unpickle your object and select
#the item you want and put it in a cStringIO or StringIO so we can open
#it directly with PIL.
F=open('allicons.dat','r')
o=pickle.load(F)
F.close()

one_im = o['1']
c = cStringIO.StringIO()
c.write(one_im)
c.seek(0)
im = Image.open(c)
im.show()
```

Comment: you could use `Image.open(StringIO(one_im))`, no need to write and seek.

Comment: It is not hard to insert images into database: [`conn.executemany('insert into images(path,image) values(?, ?)', dic.items())`](https://gist.github.com/1304181), to get an image from database knowing its path: `conn.execute('select image from images where path=?',(path,))`.

Answer (score 4):

The *sqlite3* module in the standard library would do the job nicely.

The photos are small at 2500 bits per color plane and they a can easily be stored as [blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) entries in the database (which is stored as a single file).

Comment: are you sure? I dont know if I was clear before, but I have to store not only text data (directory paths) but also the icon images themselves. I dont know well sqlite3, but I dont know if it can store non-textual information...

Comment: @alessandro yes, you can store blobs in sqlite

Comment: ooops I'm realizing how much I'm still missing (newbie in python)... what is a blob? (edited): found this http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/246207

Comment: [code example](https://gist.github.com/1304181). Add it to the answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pickle a dict that associates filenames to byte strings of RGBA data.

Assuming you have loaded the image with PIL, make sure they have all the same size and color format. Build a dict with `images[filename] = im.tostring()` and dump() it with pickle. Use `Image.fromstring` with the right size and mode parameters to get it back.